# Create function from Logic for Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, function

I have Df like this

```
      Name     PAN
 0    x     BBDFW7894Q 
 1    s         
 2    A     QWE7892E
```

i want df like this After validation PAN number

```
     Name     PAN           PAN_Status
 0    x     BBDFW7894Q      Valid PAN number
 1    s                     PAN is not present
 2    A     QWE7892E        Invalid PAN number
```

i trying with below logic

```
df["PAN_Status"] = ["Valid PAN number" if re.match(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$',ele)\
                    else ("PAN is not present"if ele==' ' else "Not Valid PAN") for ele in
```

but i want a Function for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and for second condition is tested missing values or emty strings:

```
m1 = df["PAN"].str.match(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$', na=False)
m2 = df["PAN"].str.strip().eq('') | df['PAN'].isna()

df["PAN_Status"] = np.select([m1, m2], 
                             ['Valid PAN number','PAN is not present'], 
                             'Not Valid PAN')
```

Solution with function:

```
def test(ele):
    if (ele.strip() =='') or pd.isna(ele):
        return "PAN is not present"
    elif re.match(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$',ele):
        return "Valid PAN number"
    else:
        return "Not Valid PAN"

df["PAN_Status"] = df["PAN"].apply(test)
print (df)
  Name         PAN          PAN_Status
0    x  BBDFW7894Q    Valid PAN number
1    s         NaN  PAN is not present
2    A    QWE7892E       Not Valid PAN
```

Comment: sir you are a always right but ,I want a function like
'def ():
 code
return'